# Use MonoDroid / MonoTouch to reuse DataAccess in Mobile Application

Tags: sqlite, dll, xamarin.ios, shared-libraries, xamarin.android

We have a .net desktop application that has a mobile component (Windows Mobile). The mobile component edits a specific subset of the system data. We would like to create an iPhone and Android version of this mobile app.

Is it possible to use MonoTouch and MonoDroid to compile a 'dll' in each of the respective environments which handles data access, so the apps can be written in the native environment but share the same data behavior? Basically, just focus on UI.

We are planning on using SQLite as the database, since it runs on all platforms, but we don't want to have to write the DDL and queries 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use [Mono.Data.Sqlite](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/system.data?highlight=mono.data.sqlite), which is included with both MonoTouch and Mono for Android, and provides an ADO.NET interface atop the native `sqlite` library.

On the Android side of things, I have found that Mono.Data.Sqlite is most stable with Android v2.2 and later (API level 8+), though others have reported that Android v2.1 works for them.

Comment: So, can you take the resulting 'library' and use it in a native iPhone app? We'd like to avoid using MonoTouch for the entire app if possible.